# I need to stream a logs in s3 which is coming sns .. anyone help me to achieve this

Tags: python, lambda, boto3

import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):

```
#print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
encoded_string = message.encode("utf-8")
 s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
 
 
 
 
print("From SNS: " + message)
return message
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be answer

```py
import boto3
import json
import re

def lambda_handler(event, context):
       
       
    for msg in event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']['resourceType']:
   
     #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
     message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
     encoded_string = message.encode("utf-8")
     bucket_name = "shanu9876543"
     file_name = "hello1 + msg"
    
     s3_path = "AWSLogs/" + file_name
     s3 = boto3.resource("s3")
     s3.Bucket(bucket_name).put_object(Key=s3_path, Body=encoded_string)
     
     
     
    #print("From SNS: " + message)
    #return message
```